# single linked list last node point any arbitrary node in list

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I have single linked list. Assume that the last node of the single linked list not null and point to some arbitrary node within the list instead of NULL (that mean it not `'\0'`). Therefore the linked list looped but it not point to first node. I want to find last node of linked list. Can you suggest me any algorithm to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: If the last node does not points to NULL, then its not the last node

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  It is worth spending the time to make your question readable, using proper capitalization, etc.  It also helps if you ask about the code that you've worked on, explaining what the problems with it are, showing your input, your actual output and your expected output.  Learn about how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: @Ishmeet: The list can be thought of as being like a 6 or a 9, where you start at the tail and the objective is to find the node which points back to a node already on the list.  There's only one such node; it can be considered as 'the last node' because if you start at the tail, it is the last node you visit before visiting a node you've already visited.

Comment: If my statements below are correct, I will help edit your question.  Please let me know.

Comment: [Elements of Programming](http://www.amazon.com/Elements-Programming-Alexander-Stepanov/dp/032163537X) by Stepanov & McJones covers this on pages 21-26.  The algorithms are succinct but require quite a lot of ground-work, which makes it hard to explain on SO.  It's a good book; it's also tough to get into it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler you got my question.thanks for explain in detail to understand stack overflow community  community.

Comment: @Codie CodeMonkey as you explain question more correctly than i.so please edit my question in right way to explain exact what i want to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you require.

Initialize `head` to two pointers.

```
int *temp1 = head, *temp2 = head;
```

Increment one pointer twice the step than the other pointer. If the linked list has loops the two pointers will meet at some point in the loop. Let's use `temp2` to store this meeting point node.

```
while (temp1 != temp2)
{
  temp1 = temp1->next;
  temp1 = temp1->next;

  temp2 = temp2->next;
}
```

Iterate a pointer (`temp1`) to circle the loop and count the length of it.

```
temp1 = temp1->next; // At this point temp1 is the node of the meeting point
loop_length = 0;
while (temp1 != temp2)
{
  temp1 = temp1->next;
  loop_length++;
}
```

Initialize a pointer `temp1` to `head` and advance `loop_length` number of steps.

```
temp1 = head;
while (i < loop_length)
{
  temp1 = temp1->next;
  i++;
}
```

Initialize another pointer `temp3` to `head` and then simultaneously iterate both `temp1` and `temp3` until they meet. After the loop termination both will meet at the starting point of the loop.

```
temp3 = head;
while (temp1 != temp3)
{
  temp1 = temp1->next;
  temp3 = temp3->next;
}
```

Now you can take another pointer `temp4` starting from `temp3` and traverse the list until `temp4->next` and `temp3` meet.

```
temp4 = temp3;
while (temp4->next != temp3)
{
  temp4 = temp4->next;
}
```

Now `temp4` will have the end of the list.

Comment: Thanks phoxis for reply. you got my question and your solution very useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have something like this, where the integers are just labels for the sake of naming nodes:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 2
```

I think you are asking how to detect that node 4 points to something that occurs earlier in the list.  I think from your definition, 4 would be the end of the list.  Please verify!

In this case, the easiest way to do it is to start a the beginning and step through your list, each time either marking the node as visited (if you can add data for this purpose), or keep a set structure of visited nodes.  At each step you can see if the next node is in the visited set.  If it is, you've found the last node, if it's not, you put it in the set and continue.

So for these data we get

```
current  next  visited       Comment
-------  ----  -------       -------
    1      2    {1}
    2      3    {1, 2}
    3      4    {1, 2, 3}
    4      2                 Stop, 2 is in visited, so 4 is the "last" node.
```

Comment: Thanks Codie CodeMonkey for reply.yes you got the question.but if the number of node increases  then time complexity will increase .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. You have a linked list where the last pointer is pointing back to a previous entry like so

```
This     Next      Etc.
   1        2      xxxx
   2        3      xxxxx
   3        4
   4        5
   6        3
```

So you need to keep a table of entries you have already visited. When you find a "next" value which is already in your table then the current entry is the real last entry in the list.

i.e

```
do forever
   visited[This] = "Y";
   move to Next
   if visited[Next] == "Y" 
      exit loop
   next;
```

Comment: I can understand why you may want to find the real last entry so you can fix the broken list. But why would you want to carry on using a broken link list? Surely the solution is to fix it.

Comment: @user2267155 -- yet the answer you accepted has O n! complexity (n factorial) whereas this solution is simply On.